# How do you access the menu model from a Zotonic template?

Tags: templates, zotonic

I want to write my own style of menu, but I would prefer to do it in the templates rather than making my own menu scomp.

I basically want to be able to do something like:

```
{% if m.menu %}
  <ul>
  {% for top_level_id in m.menu %}
    {% with m.rsc[top_level_id] as top_level %}
      <li><a href="{{ top_level.page_url }}">{{ top_level.title }}</a>
      {% if top_level.menu %}
        <ul>
        {% for mid_level_id in top_level.menu %}
          {% with m.rsc[mid_level_id] as mid_level %}
            <li><a href="{{ midlevel.page_url }}">{{ mid_level.title }}</a></li>
          {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

How do you access the menu model from a Zotonic template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to my previous answer. The standard `_menu.tpl` receives a list with all menu items.  This list is the result of a depth-first tree walk of the complete menu.  Every menu is a record with

```
{MenuRscId, DepthOfMenu, NrInSubMenu, HasSubMenuFlag}
```

Where the top level menu has a depth of 1 and the first menu item in a menu has a nr of 1.

All menu items that the current user is not allowed to see are filtered out.

The code of the default template:

```
<ul id="{{ id_prefix }}navigation" class="clearfix at-menu do_superfish">
{% for mid,depth,nr,has_sub in menu %}
  {% if not mid %}{% if depth > 1 %}</ul></li>{% endif %}
  {% else %}
     {% if nr == 1 and not forloop.first %}<ul{% if mid|member:path %} class="onpath"{% endif %}>{% endif %}
     <li id="{{ id_prefix }}nav-item-{{nr}}" 
         class="{% if is_first %}first {% endif %}{% if is_last %}last{% endif %}">
         <a href="{{ m.rsc[mid].page_url }}" 
            class="{{ m.rsc[mid].name }}{% if mid == id %} current{% else %}{% if mid|member:path %} onpath{% endif %}{% endif %}">{{ m.rsc[mid].short_title|default:m.rsc[mid].title }}</a>
   {% if not has_sub %}</li>{% endif %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if forloop.last %}{% include "_menu_extra.tpl" %}{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The (upcoming) 0.5-release and tip of Zotonic use a template to display the menu.  Check `mod_menu/templates/_menu.tpl`.

This template is called by the menu scomp.